# Google Cloud NLP PERSON entities

Tags: nlp, google

I'm using Google Cloud NLP Entity Recognition to recognize Persons/People, when I paste a chunk of text, it correctly provides PERSON [information](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/):

In the example:

```
"Google, headquartered in Mountain View, unveiled the new Android phone at the Consumer Electronic Show.  Sundar Pichai said in his keynote that users love their new Android phones."
```

**Sundar Pichai** is correctly identified as a person, but also the word **users**.
How can I differentiate real names vs words which refer to persons?
I have seen that for popular people there is metadata like Knowledge Graph mid or Wikipedia articles, but for others there is no reference, (Example: from "Susan Fowler" recent Uber scandal)
Any ideas/pointers will be greatly appreciated.